# How to use NSAutoreleasePool in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: macos, nsautoreleasepool, applescript-objc

I am wondering how to stop another function from a background function.
In addition, I have to drain NSAutoreleasePool, but I don't know how to do it.
I think this app sometimes freeze if I don't release pool.

```
property i : 0
property myLabel : missing value

on myStartButtonHandler_(sender)
    my performSelectorInBackground_withObject_("start", missing value) -- This code prevents "Stop" Button from freezing.
end myStartButtonHandler_

on myStopButtonHandler_(sender)
    -- I want to stop start() function and drain AutoreleasePool!
    -- I don't want to use "quit me" because I want to stop only start() function.
end myStopButtonHandler_

on start()
    repeat
        set i to i + 1
        myLabel's setIntegerValue_(i)
        delay 1
    end repeat
end start
```

You can download source code from here --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/test2.zip

For your information, I am using Xcode 4.6.3.
**EDIT**

My script has `delay 300` command, so I can't stop the function with checking the value of the variable. Sorry.

**EDIT**
I conceived of an idea to stop the function while delay commands.

```
on start()
    repeat 5 times
        if i = 1 then
            error -128
        else
            delay 60
    end repeat
end start
on myStopButtonHandler_(sender)
    set i to 1
end myStopButtonHandler_
```

I can stop the function in 60 seconds, but I can't stop it as soon as I push the stop button. So, I am still waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to stop the function is to have a variable. Check the value of the variable. If the variable is true for example then you can exit your repeat loop and drain the autorelease pool. I'm running to work now so no time to write code. Good luck.

***EDIT***: If you use an NSTimer to fire your handler, as opposed to a repeat loop, then you can invalidate the timer to stop it from running the handler. I use this to invalidate a timer because you should always check that the timer is valid before invalidating it... it will crash if you invalidate a non-valid timer.

```
-(void)deleteMyTimer {
    if ([myTimer isValid]) {
        [myTimer invalidate]
        myTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my script(not test) has `delay 300`, I can't check the value of the variable in "delay". I want to stop the function as soon as the stop button is pressed. How can I stop the function in "delay" command?

Comment: Josh said "Instead of a delay you should use an NSTimer that will call the next function when it fires", but I don't know how to check the value of the variable in NSTimer.

Comment: If you use NSTimer instead of a repeat loop, which is a really good idea, then you can invalidate the timer and it will stop the timer from firing and thus stop your handler from running. So that's what you want. You won't need a variable because you'll directly invalidate the timer. I usually use a method to invalidate a timer... I posted that code in the EDIT section of my post.

Comment: Thanks, but my project is still running with `performSelectorInBackground_withObject_`. So, I won't change delay to NSTimer in order not to make bugs.

Comment: Then my original comment applies. You need to add a variable check just after your delay. For example... if shouldStop then exit repeat. Then from your main thread you set the variable to false before you start the background thread and when you want to exit the background thread then you set shouldStop to true from the main thread. When the delay is over the repeat loop will stop. It doesn't really matter if the background thread quits as soon as you want as long as it doesn't do anything after the delay when you want to quit it. Make sense?

Comment: I made a quit button and I wrote this code: `quit me`. I decided to quit my app when the stop button is pressed, instead of only stopping the function.